# how to download the profiles of all my friends on linkedin?

Tags: python, linkedin-api

does LinkedIn provide such API for you to do so?
or does anyone aware of any scripts in python or other language to scrap all the user profile pages of all my friends?

what I am looking for is that a function that gets a list of my friends' name on Linkedin, then another function that gets the profile of any of my friend by the person's name.

Comment: Google will probably assist you with this

Comment: here i am asking how to get the profiles of all my friends, not my own profile, which i didn't find through Google. if you think a simple Google step can find the answer, please post here, i really appreciate.

Comment: Try starting here: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**Connections API**

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

along with this:

**Python interface to the LinkedIn API**

https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin

In particular:

https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin#connections-api

Comment: i actually found this on github before i post the question here, it works well to get profile of yourself, but it does not provide a wrapped function to get your friends' profiles...

Comment: Right. Use the Connections API to write that yourself.